# How do i annotate all peak values

Tags: python, matplotlib

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.signal import find_peaks
import pdb

file = open("Data1r2.txt", 'r')
lines = file.readlines()
file.close()


t = []
z = []
y = []
x = []

with open("Data1r2.txt", 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        parts = line.split(", ")
        x.append(float(parts[0][2:]))   
        y.append(float(parts[1][2:]))   
        z.append(float(parts[2][2:]))
        t.append(float(parts[3][2:]))
```

This part im mainly annotating the highest peak value of the graph, but how can i annotate all peak values at a fixed distance? say distance = 10,000

```
 fig = plt.figure()
 ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
 line, = ax.plot(t, z)
 ymax = max(z)
 xpos = z.index(ymax)
 xmax = t[xpos]
 text= "x={:.1f}, y={:.1f}".format(xmax, ymax) #Annotation(correct)

 ax.annotate(text, xy=(xmax, ymax), xytext=(xmax, ymax),
         arrowprops=dict(facecolor='black', shrink=0.05),
         )

 plt.legend()
 plt.show()
```

This is what i currently have annotating only the peak value:
[image]

Data

```
X:-241, Y:-31, Z:17, T:73823
X:-241, Y:-31, Z:17, T:73952
X:-240, Y:-30, Z:26, T:74073
X:-240, Y:-30, Z:26, T:74191
X:-240, Y:-30, Z:26, T:74312
X:-240, Y:-32, Z:39, T:74432
X:-240, Y:-32, Z:39, T:74549
X:-240, Y:-32, Z:39, T:74668
X:-239, Y:-21, Z:12, T:74785
X:-239, Y:-21, Z:12, T:74904
X:-239, Y:-21, Z:12, T:75022
X:-246, Y:15, Z:18, T:75142
X:-246, Y:15, Z:18, T:75260
X:-246, Y:15, Z:18, T:75378
X:-250, Y:19, Z:14, T:75498
X:-250, Y:19, Z:14, T:75615
X:-250, Y:19, Z:14, T:75732
X:-239, Y:-5, Z:27, T:75854
X:-239, Y:-5, Z:27, T:75972
X:-239, Y:-5, Z:27, T:76102
X:-236, Y:-19, Z:46, T:76240
X:-236, Y:-19, Z:46, T:76369
X:-236, Y:-19, Z:46, T:76489
X:-235, Y:-14, Z:32, T:76610
X:-235, Y:-14, Z:32, T:76727
X:-235, Y:-14, Z:32, T:76845
X:-244, Y:-16, Z:22, T:76963
X:-244, Y:-16, Z:22, T:77081
X:-244, Y:-16, Z:22, T:77201
X:-220, Y:-25, Z:-3, T:77346
X:-220, Y:-25, Z:-3, T:77464
X:-220, Y:-25, Z:-3, T:77580
X:-229, Y:24, Z:2, T:77699
X:-229, Y:24, Z:2, T:77814
X:-229, Y:24, Z:2, T:77934
X:-248, Y:-20, Z:0, T:78052
X:-248, Y:-20, Z:0, T:78171
X:-248, Y:-20, Z:0, T:78288
X:-242, Y:-15, Z:-35, T:78515
X:-242, Y:-15, Z:-35, T:78630
X:-242, Y:-15, Z:-35, T:78747
X:-235, Y:-12, Z:-63, T:78865
X:-235, Y:-12, Z:-63, T:78982
X:-235, Y:-12, Z:-63, T:79102
X:-226, Y:-35, Z:-145, T:79221
X:-226, Y:-35, Z:-145, T:79340
X:-226, Y:-35, Z:-145, T:79461
X:-205, Y:-47, Z:-156, T:79582
X:-205, Y:-47, Z:-156, T:79702
X:-205, Y:-47, Z:-156, T:79821
X:-208, Y:-39, Z:-149, T:79940
X:-208, Y:-39, Z:-149, T:80061
X:-208, Y:-39, Z:-149, T:80181
X:-235, Y:-16, Z:-99, T:80304
X:-235, Y:-16, Z:-99, T:80432
X:-235, Y:-16, Z:-99, T:80657
X:-247, Y:-10, Z:12, T:80774
X:-247, Y:-10, Z:12, T:80890
X:-247, Y:-10, Z:12, T:81008
X:-242, Y:-1, Z:2, T:81127
X:-242, Y:-1, Z:2, T:81246
X:-242, Y:-1, Z:2, T:81363
X:-239, Y:-8, Z:15, T:81483
X:-239, Y:-8, Z:15, T:81600
X:-239, Y:-8, Z:15, T:81720
X:-241, Y:-13, Z:-11, T:81841
X:-241, Y:-13, Z:-11, T:81958
X:-241, Y:-13, Z:-11, T:82076
X:-242, Y:-5, Z:-37, T:82198
X:-242, Y:-5, Z:-37, T:82315
X:-242, Y:-5, Z:-37, T:82435
X:-215, Y:-43, Z:-128, T:82554
X:-215, Y:-43, Z:-128, T:82699
X:-215, Y:-43, Z:-128, T:82829
X:-207, Y:-48, Z:-153, T:82952
X:-207, Y:-48, Z:-153, T:83072
X:-207, Y:-48, Z:-153, T:83191
X:-198, Y:-37, Z:-166, T:83315
X:-198, Y:-37, Z:-166, T:83453
X:-198, Y:-37, Z:-166, T:83572
X:-218, Y:-33, Z:-134, T:83694
X:-218, Y:-33, Z:-134, T:83812
X:-218, Y:-33, Z:-134, T:83932
X:-228, Y:-15, Z:-80, T:84047
X:-228, Y:-15, Z:-80, T:84166
X:-228, Y:-15, Z:-80, T:84288
X:-243, Y:-8, Z:-4, T:84407
X:-243, Y:-8, Z:-4, T:84524
X:-243, Y:-8, Z:-4, T:84640
X:-238, Y:-4, Z:2, T:84756
X:-238, Y:-4, Z:2, T:84872
X:-238, Y:-4, Z:2, T:84994
X:-252, Y:-7, Z:-16, T:85136
X:-252, Y:-7, Z:-16, T:85265
X:-252, Y:-7, Z:-16, T:85385
X:-243, Y:-3, Z:-28, T:85504
X:-243, Y:-3, Z:-28, T:85618
X:-243, Y:-3, Z:-28, T:85739
X:-241, Y:-3, Z:-48, T:85858
X:-241, Y:-3, Z:-48, T:85975
X:-241, Y:-3, Z:-48, T:86094
X:-231, Y:-15, Z:-112, T:86216
X:-231, Y:-15, Z:-112, T:86334
X:-231, Y:-15, Z:-112, T:86453
X:-210, Y:-43, Z:-150, T:86573
X:-210, Y:-43, Z:-150, T:86691
X:-210, Y:-43, Z:-150, T:86811
X:-193, Y:-58, Z:-169, T:86933
X:-193, Y:-58, Z:-169, T:87051
X:-193, Y:-58, Z:-169, T:87171
X:-182, Y:-27, Z:-179, T:87305
X:-182, Y:-27, Z:-179, T:87435
X:-182, Y:-27, Z:-179, T:87566
X:-212, Y:-19, Z:-136, T:87686
X:-212, Y:-19, Z:-136, T:87803
X:-212, Y:-19, Z:-136, T:87920
X:-233, Y:-25, Z:-83, T:88040
X:-233, Y:-25, Z:-83, T:88160
X:-233, Y:-25, Z:-83, T:88278
X:-243, Y:-16, Z:-31, T:88396
X:-243, Y:-16, Z:-31, T:88510
X:-243, Y:-16, Z:-31, T:88625
X:-244, Y:-13, Z:-27, T:88744
X:-244, Y:-13, Z:-27, T:88860
X:-244, Y:-13, Z:-27, T:88978
X:-243, Y:-15, Z:-51, T:89099
X:-243, Y:-15, Z:-51, T:89218
X:-243, Y:-15, Z:-51, T:89338
X:-228, Y:-27, Z:-78, T:89472
X:-228, Y:-27, Z:-78, T:89601
X:-228, Y:-27, Z:-78, T:89746
X:-223, Y:-24, Z:-114, T:89876
X:-223, Y:-24, Z:-114, T:89995
X:-223, Y:-24, Z:-114, T:90115
X:-205, Y:-42, Z:-141, T:90236
X:-205, Y:-42, Z:-141, T:90354
X:-205, Y:-42, Z:-141, T:90474
X:-199, Y:-67, Z:-153, T:90595
X:-199, Y:-67, Z:-153, T:90713
X:-199, Y:-67, Z:-153, T:90833
X:-202, Y:-53, Z:-152, T:90951
X:-202, Y:-53, Z:-152, T:91069
X:-202, Y:-53, Z:-152, T:91191
X:-224, Y:-41, Z:-135, T:91312
X:-224, Y:-41, Z:-135, T:91431
X:-224, Y:-41, Z:-135, T:91549
X:-229, Y:-29, Z:-91, T:91669
X:-229, Y:-29, Z:-91, T:91789
X:-229, Y:-29, Z:-91, T:91923
X:-242, Y:-8, Z:-2, T:92066
X:-242, Y:-8, Z:-2, T:92184
X:-242, Y:-8, Z:-2, T:92302
X:-233, Y:-12, Z:-5, T:92420
X:-233, Y:-12, Z:-5, T:92534
X:-233, Y:-12, Z:-5, T:92654
X:-246, Y:-1, Z:-4, T:92773
X:-246, Y:-1, Z:-4, T:92892
X:-246, Y:-1, Z:-4, T:93010
X:-242, Y:-9, Z:-23, T:93130
X:-242, Y:-9, Z:-23, T:93251
X:-242, Y:-9, Z:-23, T:93370
X:-237, Y:-19, Z:-46, T:93491
X:-237, Y:-19, Z:-46, T:93608
X:-237, Y:-19, Z:-46, T:93727
X:-213, Y:-23, Z:-95, T:93849
X:-213, Y:-23, Z:-95, T:93966
X:-213, Y:-23, Z:-95, T:94112
X:-207, Y:-36, Z:-151, T:94241
X:-207, Y:-36, Z:-151, T:94359
X:-207, Y:-36, Z:-151, T:94480
X:-199, Y:-49, Z:-162, T:94600
X:-199, Y:-49, Z:-162, T:94721
X:-199, Y:-49, Z:-162, T:94840
X:-203, Y:-36, Z:-146, T:94961
X:-203, Y:-36, Z:-146, T:95082
X:-203, Y:-36, Z:-146, T:95202
X:-222, Y:-28, Z:-124, T:95324
X:-222, Y:-28, Z:-124, T:95439
X:-222, Y:-28, Z:-124, T:95583
X:-244, Y:2, Z:-53, T:95700
X:-244, Y:2, Z:-53, T:95817
X:-244, Y:2, Z:-53, T:95935
X:-237, Y:-5, Z:-9, T:96055
X:-237, Y:-5, Z:-9, T:96171
X:-237, Y:-5, Z:-9, T:96301
X:-239, Y:-2, Z:1, T:96439
X:-239, Y:-2, Z:1, T:96568
X:-239, Y:-2, Z:1, T:96685
X:-243, Y:-4, Z:2, T:96805
X:-243, Y:-4, Z:2, T:96919
X:-243, Y:-4, Z:2, T:97037
X:-246, Y:-3, Z:-16, T:97159
X:-246, Y:-3, Z:-16, T:97276
X:-246, Y:-3, Z:-16, T:97395
X:-239, Y:-8, Z:-42, T:97513
X:-239, Y:-8, Z:-42, T:97631
X:-239, Y:-8, Z:-42, T:97752
X:-221, Y:-10, Z:-115, T:97871
X:-221, Y:-10, Z:-115, T:97990
X:-221, Y:-10, Z:-115, T:98109
X:-219, Y:-25, Z:-145, T:98230
X:-219, Y:-25, Z:-145, T:98350
X:-219, Y:-25, Z:-145, T:98468
X:-202, Y:-31, Z:-172, T:98589
X:-202, Y:-31, Z:-172, T:98736
X:-202, Y:-31, Z:-172, T:98865
X:-214, Y:-34, Z:-144, T:98985
X:-214, Y:-34, Z:-144, T:99101
X:-214, Y:-34, Z:-144, T:99223
X:-224, Y:-24, Z:-116, T:99342
X:-224, Y:-24, Z:-116, T:99460
X:-224, Y:-24, Z:-116, T:99579
X:-232, Y:2, Z:-50, T:99699
X:-232, Y:2, Z:-50, T:99818
X:-232, Y:2, Z:-50, T:99936
X:-241, Y:-4, Z:-22, T:100056
X:-241, Y:-4, Z:-22, T:100175
X:-241, Y:-4, Z:-22, T:100293
X:-240, Y:4, Z:-2, T:100414
X:-240, Y:4, Z:-2, T:100532
X:-240, Y:4, Z:-2, T:100648
X:-241, Y:3, Z:1, T:100768
X:-241, Y:3, Z:1, T:100895
X:-241, Y:3, Z:1, T:101029
X:-243, Y:1, Z:-16, T:101160
X:-243, Y:1, Z:-16, T:101278
X:-243, Y:1, Z:-16, T:101399
X:-239, Y:-2, Z:-36, T:101518
X:-239, Y:-2, Z:-36, T:101661
X:-239, Y:-2, Z:-36, T:101780
X:-228, Y:-12, Z:-71, T:101901
X:-228, Y:-12, Z:-71, T:102019
X:-228, Y:-12, Z:-71, T:102138
X:-224, Y:-23, Z:-118, T:102260
X:-224, Y:-23, Z:-118, T:102378
X:-224, Y:-23, Z:-118, T:102498
X:-209, Y:-2, Z:-161, T:102617
X:-209, Y:-2, Z:-161, T:102735
X:-209, Y:-2, Z:-161, T:102855
X:-206, Y:-3, Z:-150, T:102974
X:-206, Y:-3, Z:-150, T:103088
X:-206, Y:-3, Z:-150, T:103216
X:-218, Y:0, Z:-142, T:103355
X:-218, Y:0, Z:-142, T:103469
X:-218, Y:0, Z:-142, T:103581
X:-226, Y:-17, Z:-118, T:103700
X:-226, Y:-17, Z:-118, T:103814
X:-226, Y:-17, Z:-118, T:103931
X:-242, Y:4, Z:-40, T:104054
X:-242, Y:4, Z:-40, T:104171
X:-242, Y:4, Z:-40, T:104292
X:-242, Y:4, Z:-22, T:104410
X:-242, Y:4, Z:-22, T:104523
X:-242, Y:4, Z:-22, T:104642
X:-240, Y:5, Z:-3, T:104762
X:-240, Y:5, Z:-3, T:104879
X:-240, Y:5, Z:-3, T:104993
X:-244, Y:-2, Z:-6, T:105111
X:-244, Y:-2, Z:-6, T:105231
X:-244, Y:-2, Z:-6, T:105361
X:-244, Y:1, Z:-10, T:105497
X:-244, Y:1, Z:-10, T:105623
X:-244, Y:1, Z:-10, T:105744
X:-244, Y:-4, Z:-34, T:105865
X:-244, Y:-4, Z:-34, T:105981
X:-244, Y:-4, Z:-34, T:106101
X:-231, Y:-1, Z:-63, T:106222
X:-231, Y:-1, Z:-63, T:106341
X:-231, Y:-1, Z:-63, T:106462
X:-222, Y:-11, Z:-116, T:106580
X:-222, Y:-11, Z:-116, T:106698
X:-222, Y:-11, Z:-116, T:106818
X:-219, Y:-15, Z:-144, T:106938
X:-219, Y:-15, Z:-144, T:107058
X:-219, Y:-15, Z:-144, T:107174
X:-204, Y:-6, Z:-150, T:107297
X:-204, Y:-6, Z:-150, T:107410
X:-204, Y:-6, Z:-150, T:107528
X:-196, Y:-5, Z:-163, T:107665
X:-196, Y:-5, Z:-163, T:107802
X:-196, Y:-5, Z:-163, T:107935
X:-214, Y:-2, Z:-153, T:108066
X:-214, Y:-2, Z:-153, T:108186
X:-214, Y:-2, Z:-153, T:108306
X:-223, Y:-12, Z:-123, T:108422
X:-223, Y:-12, Z:-123, T:108544
X:-223, Y:-12, Z:-123, T:108661
X:-230, Y:7, Z:-52, T:108783
X:-230, Y:7, Z:-52, T:108900
X:-230, Y:7, Z:-52, T:109019
X:-241, Y:9, Z:-25, T:109139
X:-241, Y:9, Z:-25, T:109258
X:-241, Y:9, Z:-25, T:109375
X:-245, Y:4, Z:-12, T:109496
X:-245, Y:4, Z:-12, T:109612
X:-245, Y:4, Z:-12, T:109732
X:-242, Y:3, Z:-6, T:109852
X:-242, Y:3, Z:-6, T:109968
X:-242, Y:3, Z:-6, T:110098
X:-239, Y:-4, Z:-35, T:110243
X:-239, Y:-4, Z:-35, T:110362
X:-239, Y:-4, Z:-35, T:110484
X:-235, Y:6, Z:-65, T:110606
X:-235, Y:6, Z:-65, T:110722
X:-235, Y:6, Z:-65, T:110840
X:-215, Y:-14, Z:-117, T:110962
X:-215, Y:-14, Z:-117, T:111081
X:-215, Y:-14, Z:-117, T:111204
X:-224, Y:7, Z:-146, T:111324
X:-224, Y:7, Z:-146, T:111441
X:-224, Y:7, Z:-146, T:111561
X:-209, Y:-6, Z:-149, T:111679
X:-209, Y:-6, Z:-149, T:111799
X:-209, Y:-6, Z:-149, T:111919
X:-219, Y:-8, Z:-140, T:112038
X:-219, Y:-8, Z:-140, T:112157
X:-219, Y:-8, Z:-140, T:112274
X:-226, Y:-3, Z:-116, T:112405
X:-226, Y:-3, Z:-116, T:112540
X:-226, Y:-3, Z:-116, T:112669
X:-233, Y:2, Z:-76, T:112792
X:-233, Y:2, Z:-76, T:112909
X:-233, Y:2, Z:-76, T:113028
X:-237, Y:7, Z:-35, T:113148
X:-237, Y:7, Z:-35, T:113266
X:-237, Y:7, Z:-35, T:113386
X:-242, Y:5, Z:-15, T:113504
X:-242, Y:5, Z:-15, T:113624
X:-242, Y:5, Z:-15, T:113764
X:-244, Y:5, Z:-3, T:113884
X:-244, Y:5, Z:-3, T:113999
X:-244, Y:5, Z:-3, T:114118
X:-242, Y:3, Z:-7, T:114239
X:-242, Y:3, Z:-7, T:114357
X:-242, Y:3, Z:-7, T:114473
X:-241, Y:0, Z:-30, T:114595
X:-241, Y:0, Z:-30, T:114720
X:-241, Y:0, Z:-30, T:114867
X:-227, Y:-13, Z:-95, T:114989
X:-227, Y:-13, Z:-95, T:115104
X:-227, Y:-13, Z:-95, T:115224
X:-212, Y:-5, Z:-114, T:115343
X:-212, Y:-5, Z:-114, T:115462
X:-212, Y:-5, Z:-114, T:115579
X:-215, Y:-6, Z:-145, T:115701
X:-215, Y:-6, Z:-145, T:115819
X:-215, Y:-6, Z:-145, T:115937
X:-210, Y:5, Z:-142, T:116059
X:-210, Y:5, Z:-142, T:116176
X:-210, Y:5, Z:-142, T:116296
X:-222, Y:-19, Z:-145, T:116415
X:-222, Y:-19, Z:-145, T:116534
X:-222, Y:-19, Z:-145, T:116655
X:-231, Y:6, Z:-119, T:116775
X:-231, Y:6, Z:-119, T:116894
X:-231, Y:6, Z:-119, T:117023
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Peak detection algorithm in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50756793/peak-detection-algorithm-in-python)

Comment: Is the problem you are having with *finding* the peaks? or *annotating* the peaks?

Comment: the problem im having is annotating the peaks, but in a way where i wont have to state the x and y for the annotation, the code will detect all peaks and there after annotate the peak values accordingly

Comment: annotating the peaks, so there is 8 peaks, i need my data to show 9 annotation of the values x = ? , y = ?

Comment: So, did you ever solve this?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's something ready in matplotlib - the task of peak detection is hard and the notion of peak can vary greatly from application to application.

Since your data is relatively simple, you can try an approach inspired by a Schmitt trigger: look for recent high values but discard small oscillations. The (pseudo) code would be:

```
y_max = None

for y in data:
  if y_max is None:  # start tracking
    y_max = y

  if y > y_max:  # update max value
    y_max = y

  if y < y_max * 0.9:   # signal is too different from
    add_label(y=y_max)  # the peak - save the peak and
    y_max = None        # start looking for another one
```

Comment: You can also exchange `if y < y_max * 0.9` with `if y < y_max - 10000` to use a fixed difference (as mentioned by OP).